# What is the corrrect form of pronoun to use for note taking?

Tags: pronouns

I am trying to take notes on a lecture that others can access online.

Should I write:

> To understand depression, one must understand both biology and
> psychology.

or

> You must understand both psychology and biology to understand
> depression.

These are notes that others can read online that go along with the video lecture.

Is it just a matter of preference or is there a correct way to do it?

Comment: **You** is more engaging than some anonymous *one*, and you do want the reader to care.

Comment: Whether you are taking notes makes no difference at all to the answer.

Comment: The notes should reflect the speaker.

Comment: Is there a correct answer, or is this just preference.  The duplicate just says that one is more formal.  These are notes I want to publish for readability, so that say instead of watching a 1 hour lecture one could just read the one page notes ... similar to Cliff Notes I guess but much shorter.  This question is more specific and for notes.